# different result from SELECT and from SELECT inside a VIEW

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-view

Result from SELECT statement is different from the result from SELECT inside VIEW. How to fix the problem and get the same result from in view?

actions table:

```
+--+---------+--------------+-----------+------+
|id|person_id|action_type_id|currency_id|sum   |
+--+---------+--------------+-----------+------+
|1 |1        |1             |1          | 1.00 |
|2 |1        |1             |1          | 5.00 |
|3 |1        |1             |2          |10.00 | 
|4 |1        |2             |1          | 2.00 |
|5 |2        |1             |1          |20.00 |
|6 |2        |2             |2          | 5.00 |
+--+---------+--------------+-----------+------+
```

select:

```
SELECT person_id AS p, currency_id AS c,
(
CAST(
COALESCE(
(SELECT SUM(sum) FROM actions WHERE action_type_id=1 AND person_id=p AND currency_id=c)
, 0)
AS DECIMAL(11,2)) -
CAST(
COALESCE(
(SELECT SUM(sum) FROM actions WHERE action_type_id=2 AND person_id=p AND currency_id=c)
, 0)
AS DECIMAL(11,2))
) AS sum
FROM actions
GROUP BY currency_id, person_id
ORDER BY person_id, currency_id;
```

Result:

```
+--+--+------+
|p |c |sum   |
+--+--+------+
|1 |1 | 4.00 |
|1 |2 |10.00 |
|2 |1 |20.00 |
|2 |2 |-5.00 |
+--+--+------+
```

select inside view:

```
CREATE VIEW p_sums AS
SELECT person_id AS p, currency_id AS c,
(
CAST(
COALESCE(
(SELECT SUM(sum) FROM actions WHERE action_type_id=1 AND person_id=p AND currency_id=c)
, 0)
AS DECIMAL(11,2)) -
CAST(
COALESCE(
(SELECT SUM(sum) FROM actions WHERE action_type_id=2 AND person_id=p AND currency_id=c)
, 0)
AS DECIMAL(11,2))
) AS sum
FROM actions
GROUP BY currency_id, person_id
ORDER BY person_id, currency_id;

SELECT * FROM p_sums;
```

Result:

```
+--+--+------+
|p |c |sum   |
+--+--+------+
|1 |1 |29.00 |
|1 |2 |29.00 |
|2 |1 |29.00 |
|2 |2 |29.00 |
+--+--+------+
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Just FYI, for newbies (I too was one), when someone helps offer a solution, and it IS the one that gets you beyond your stump, its a courtesy to click the checkbox under their answer to give them credit so others know the solution is already resolved.

Comment: i did so but, it is made me wait 60 seconds before i could accept the answer:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not do:

```
SELECT person_id AS p, currency_id AS c, SUM(CASE action_Type_id WHEN 1 THEN sum WHEN 2 THEN -sum END) as sum
FROM actions
GROUP BY currency_id, person_id
ORDER BY person_id, currency_id;
```

I.e. get rid of the subqueries, and just build a single sum up (making action_type_id 2 values negative)

Comment: it works! and it is so much elegant. thank you very very much!!